# What constitutes "sending" Manot?

Tags: halacha, time, mitzvah, mishloach-manot, conditional-stipulation

On Purim, I will drive around and deliver my mishloach manot. However, if a person is not home, I might leave the package at his door. If he doesn't arrive until days later, have I still satisfied my obligation to send because I delivered it to his door on the right day? Does it matter if I know that he is not (or will not be) home?

If I know he isn't home on Ta'anit Esther, can I leave it at his door then, knowing that he won't get home until it is properly Purim, so the actual receiving of it will be on Purim. Could I leave it a week early (or longer) if I know he won't be around until Purim?

This last one just popped into my head and might need a separate question -- I don't know the rules of conditions well enough. If I am visiting a friend on Ta'anit Esther and I won't see him on Purim, can I put a package in his house and say "I am placing this here but not transferring ownership of it to you until tomorrow"? Could I do that on the day before the fast with a longer conditional period?

Comment: If you look at mitzvas in a way that HaShem is (as if) standing there with a clib board waiting to make a check next to our name then there could be room to ask such a question. However if we look at mitzvas in a simple way, the megillah says to send manos to people and give money/food to the poor then if you've done all you could to make sure the food and or money gets to the proper place then the mitzvah was done. Anything else is "check mark Judaism". Still a nice question though...

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Heinemann said in a shiur at Ner Yisroel Baltimore, "If you leave the משלוח מנות outside someone’s house which is a חצר המשתמרת, then you’re יוצא. If it’s not משתמרת or the area outside his door isn’t his property, then you cannot be יוצא with merely leaving the משלוח מנות there."